# What are trained models in NLP?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am new to Natural language processing. Can anyone tell me what are the trained models in either OpenNLP or Stanford CoreNLP? While coding in java using apache openNLP package, we always have to include some trained models (found here http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/ ). What are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "model" [as downloadable for OpenNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) is [a set of data representing a set of probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model) used for predicting the structure you want (e.g. [part-of-speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech) tags) from the input you supply (in the case of OpenNLP, typically text files).

Given that natural language is [context-sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#As_model_of_natural_languages)<sup>†</sup>, this model is used in lieu of a rule-based system because it generally works better than the latter for [a number of reasons](http://stp.lingfil.uu.se/~nivre/docs/statnlp.pdf) which I won't expound here for the sake of brevity. For example, as [you already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403862/what-are-trained-models-in-nlp#comment-70027854), the token *perfect* could be either a verb (`VB`) or an adjective (`JJ`) and this can only be disambiguated in context:

- *This answer is perfect* — for this example, the following sequences of POS tags are possible (in addition to many more<sup>‡</sup>):

  1. `DT NN VBZ JJ`
  2. `DT NN VBZ VB`

However, according to a model which accurately represents ("correct") English<sup>§</sup>, the probability of example 1 is greater than of example 2: `P([DT, NN, VBZ, JJ] | ["This", "answer", "is", "perfect"]) > P([DT, NN, VBZ, VB] | ["This", "answer", "is", "perfect"])`

---

<sup>†</sup>In reality, this is quite contentious, but I stress here that I'm talking about natural language as a whole (including semantics/pragmatics/etc.) and not just about natural-language *syntax*, which (in the case of English, at least) [is considered by some to be context-free](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-009-3401-6_13).

<sup>‡</sup>When analyzing language in a data-driven manner, in fact *any* combination of POS tags is "possible", but, given a sample of "correct" contemporary English with little noise, tag assignments which native speakers would judge to be "wrong" should have an extremely low probability of occurrence.

<sup>§</sup>In practice, this means a model trained on a large, diverse corpus of (contemporary) English (or some other target domain you want to analyze) with appropriate tuning parameters (If I want to be even more precise, this footnote could easily be multiple paragraphs long).

Comment: Would you explain more how it is a set of probability distributions used for predicting the structure you want?, did you mean if i input for example the word "perfect" in a sentence ,perfect can be adj or verb ,so the model will decide adj or verb according to the highest probability from sentence analysis, is that correct?

Comment: I added an explicit example; Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, it is clearer now to me, but there is another problem which is the accuracy of tagging, Stanford coreNLP and OpenNLP fail in identifying the word _perfect_ as a verb in cases like _"To perfect"_ while [this online NLTK tagger](http://textanalysisonline.com/nltk-pos-tagging) do it right, so is there anything to do to handle such cases in Stanford coreNLP tagger?

Comment: What you asked is potentially very complicated and thus is a question unto itself, beyond the scope of this question: Stanford and OpenNLP come with pre-trained models which are generally quite good, so it is likely due to one or more of many other factors and thus I'd need a lot more information than what you provided.

Comment: OK, for this example _"She works hard to perfect her writing."_ i get these POS tags "She_PRP works_VBZ hard_JJ to_TO perfect_JJ her_PRP$ writing_NN ._." , there are two wrong tags , "hard" has to be adverb and "perfect" has to be verb, i don't know what's wrong may be the model is not trained to identify "perfect" as a verb in this case, so what should i do?

Comment: As I already stated, this is in no way enough information for me to give you an answer; Write a proper question, describing how you actually get the results and I'll try to answer it if I find it.

Answer (score -1):

Think of trained model as a "wise brain with existing information".

When you start out machine learning, the brain for your model is clean and empty. You can either download trained model or you can train your own model (like teaching a child)

Usually you only train models for edge cases else you download "Trained models" and get to work in predicting/machine learning.